# Android Studio reading and writing data via Bluetooth

Tags: android

I am currently writing an app which connects 2 paired devices and allows them to send data to one another. I'm very new to Android development and I'm having some problems, I can't seem to get the data transmission working.

I have been following this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Here's some of my code:

-The "Send" button, meant to send a string over

```
btnSendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = editTxtMsg.getText().toString();

            if (connectedThread != null) {
                connectedThread.write(message.getBytes());
            }
        }
    });
```

-The ConnectedThread

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();

                /*Bundle data =new Bundle();
                //data.p
                Message m =mHandler.obtainMessage();

                m.setData(data);
                mHandler.sendMessage(m);*/

            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);

            mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

-The handler

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String readMessage = new String(readBuffer, 0, msg.arg1);
                //arrayAdapterMsg.add(btDevice.getName() + ": " + readMessage);
                aryLstMsg.add(btDevice.getName() + ": " + readMessage);

                arrayAdapterMsg.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;

            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuffer);
                //arrayAdapterMsg.add("Me: " + "test");
                aryLstMsg.add("Me: " + writeMessage);

                arrayAdapterMsg.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;
        }
    }
};
```

I don't know why it's not working, does anybody else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

check bluetooth permission 
it should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access buffer from write() function , but it is defined inside run(). Try to define it globally or call write() from run by passing suitable parameters.